# how do i make a div with inline contents?

Tags: css, html

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhrYD.png here is a screenshot

I am trying to style it such that the h1 will sit on the left, the input is in the middle, and then I want to have some links on the right.

I tried using float and it just ruins everything.

**Edit**

When I used float: left or float: right, I get 2 divs to separate but the positioning is awful.

Some html I have:

```
<div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="nytm">
                    <h1>New York Tech Map</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="form">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="zip">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search By Zip">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="navlinks">
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#header {
    background: #EDEDED;
    height: 79px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;  
}

#nytm{
    display: inline;
}

#form{
    margin-top: 24px;
    display: inline;
}

#navlinks{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: write the code please :)

Comment: Speak english man, I have no idea what you're talking about.  What does "the will sit on the left" and "the is in the middle" even mean?

Comment: @Jack lol, i put tags in so i guess they disappeared.

Comment: don't use display: inline, just use float: left for navlinks, form and nytm, maybe there is need to set float: left for div with header id too.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/qvL55/, please explain what is wrong with it

Comment: @JuanMendes i thought i was asking the questions -.-!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way i would do this is first make one large div, then put each field into their own divs, this creates a large div with equal spaced divs inside it, itll be easier to do css on it then.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, follow this steps:

In you'r css file, put this `clearfix` styled class:

```
    .clearfix:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;visibility:hidden;line-height:0;height:0;}
    .clearfix{display:inline-block;}
    html[xmlns] .clearfix{display:block;}
    * html .clearfix{height:1%;}

    .fr{float:right;display:inline-block;}
    .fl{float:left;display:inline-block;}
```

You will need this class for the next section.

Now let's see what we need in the `HTML` section:

```
    <div class="clearfix container">
        <div class="fl search-zone">
            <!-- YOUR SEARCH INPUT AND BUTTON HERE -->
            <input type="text" /> <button>SEARCH</button>
        </div>
        <div class="fr links">
            <!-- YOUR LINKS HERE -->
            <a href="">LINK 1</a> <a href="">LINK 2</a> <a href="">LINK 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

- The `clearfix` class will help you position inside it any floating element and it's a cross-browser solution for that.
  *it is highly recommended to give to the classes `search-zone` and `links` a `width` to prevent IE problems.

Hope this is what you looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Check it here, why their positioning is awful while using floating. i adjust css and see output

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Bq9eq/
```

Comment: ya, i did that same thing after listening to emilan haha, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is three that you want there columns of on your header.

One way of doing it is to create three separate divs.

```
<div class="top-container"></div> 
<div class="top-container"></div> 
<div class="top-container"></div>
```

Clearfix the container and float the children

```
#header .top-container{
  width:33%;
  float:left;
}
```

Check this fiddle for the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/xZC3G/2/

Comment: There are more flexible ways of adding columns... you could choose different widths for each, nest them and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure what you mean, but keep in mind that every new div is a block level element, so it gets its own row, unless you tell it otherwise.  Try using display:inline with your float.

Comment: I did use display:inline but nothing happens.